# How do I add an image in the QToolbar using PyQt?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt

I'm creating a tool bar in PyQt. How it looks now is:

(HomeButton).............................................(ExitButton)..|

I want to use the space in the middle to put in an image/logo -- with no function so it looks like:

(homebutton)......[IMAGE/LOGO_HERE]......(exitbutton)..|

I've tried to do this by adding a widget with  an image but it's not showing up. My code is:

```
    logo = QWidget()
    logolabel = QLabel(p3logo)
    logopixmap = QPixmap(self.LOGO)
    logolabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.LOGO))
    logolabel.setPixmap(logopixmap)
    logo.resize(logopixmap.width(),logopixmap.height())

    ###logoAction = QAction(QIcon('logo.png'), 'Logo', self)


    spacer = QWidget()
    spacer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
    exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+X')
    exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exitClicked)

    homeAction = QAction(QIcon('home.png'), 'Home', self)
    homeAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+H')
    homeAction.triggered.connect(self.homeClicked)



    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Toolbar')
    self.toolbar.addAction(homeAction)
    self.toolbar.addWidget(logo)
    ###self.toolbar.addAction(logoAction)
    self.toolbar.addWidget(spacer)
    self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)
    self.toolbar.addSeparator()
```

I also tried to add it in as an 'icon' but it was resized to the same size as the home/exit buttons making it hardly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example is effectively just adding an empty widget to the toolbar, because the label has not been put inside a layout. It looks like it can be fixed by getting rid of the container widget and simply adding the label directly:

```
self.toolbar.addWidget(logolabel)
```